# acp.vim acts strangely in Vim 7.4

Tags: vim

When I updated my vim from Vim 7.3 to Vim 7.4, I found that acp.vim works strangely. In Vim 7.3, when the number of letters I type in isn't less than `g:acp_behaviorKeywordLength`, `acp` pops up. But in Vim 7.4, only when the number of letters I type in is equal to `g:acp_behaviorKeywordLength`, `acp` pops up. How can I get acp.vim in Vim 7.4 works the same as in Vim 7.3?

Comment: You are using too many negatives in your question: it's hard to see what you get and what you want. Anyway, what is the value of `g:acp_behaviorKeywordLength`? Supposing it's 2, the completion popup should appear as soon as you have typed 2 characters *and* there's a completion available. FWIW, AutoComplPop works just as well in 7.4 as it did in 7.3 for me.

Comment: Okay. Supposing I want to type in word 'include', in Vim 7.3, when I type in 'in' acp pops up a completion and if I type 'c' or 'cl' or more, the completion doesn't disappear. But in Vim 7.4, when I type 'c' or 'cl' or more after 'in', the completion disappears.

Comment: I get the correct behavior in 7.4. Tell us more about your config, please.

Comment: I use acp.vim, c.vim and snipMate.vim at the same time, and only have `let g:acp_behaviorKeywordCommand = "\<C-n>"`.